# Variable cannot be set

Tags: variables, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my first time here. I used to program 20 years ago in Turbo Pascal and some database management, then I got into Med School.

I am managing an spreadsheet of patients that must be seen by certain therapists. I make one sheet weekly on Google Spreadsheets, shaped as a calendar. There's 16 time columns and 5 groups of 6 rows each, for 5 days and 6 therapists, respectively. The cells hold the names of the patients and are validated against a list of names that's filled below on the first column. The spreadsheet itself counts how many sessions each patient has.

The second part is a small program that runs through every patient, then every day, then every hour and then every therapist. If the name of the patient matches, it prints the day in bold, then the time and then the therapist he has an appointment with.

After each iteration it compares against the previous match: If the day does not match, it will print a new day in bold. If it matches, it will print the time only. It gets the day (name and number) from the last column in the spreadsheet that turns the date for each day into a more legible format.

My problem is: Whenever a patient starts at the same day as the patient before finished, the variable matches and the day is not written.

I have tried to change the value of the variable (*diaprevio*) by using `var diaprevio=""`, `var diaprevio = 0`, `var diaprevio = diaprevio+diaprevio`, `var diaprevio = dia.getvalue()+1` and even `delete diaprevio`, but nothing changes. I have confirmed the problem is *diaprevio* keeping its value because whenever that happens, if I add the former patient in a different day, the problem resolves.

The code is the following:

```
/* Funciones para generar horarios a partir del calendario
Esta escanea las celdas de calendario de derecha a izquierda y arriba a abajo
Para encontrar el texto coincidente y lo entrega en un documento de texto.
*/

function TerapeutaHora() {

  var activ = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = activ.getActiveSheet(); //Selecciona la hoja activa, no una hoja fija
  var planning = sheet.getRange("A1:S36"); // Rango del calendario + la lista de días
  var ListaPacientes = sheet.getRange("A45:A72"); // Rango de los pacientes activos
  var dia=planning.getCell(1,1);
  doc = DocumentApp.create("Horario"); // Crea un nuevo documento llamado Horario
  var docu = doc.getBody()

  //Primero hacemos que pase por los pacientes activos

   for (var p=1; p < 29; p++) {
     var pacientesource=ListaPacientes.getCell(p,1)

     var par = docu.appendParagraph(pacientesource.getValue())
     par.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2) //Pone el nombre del paciente en HEADING

    //Luego que pase por las filas y las columnas
     for (var d = 0; d < 5; d++){ //cinco días
       for (var b = 1; b < 18; b++){ //18 columnas de horario
         for (var a = 3; a < 9; a++){ //Los 6 nombres
           var columna = (d*7 +a) //Los 7 espacios entre un día y otro
           var pacienteplanning=planning.getCell(columna, b) //Lee el paciente y lo compara con el que está eligiendo en este momento
           var coincidencia = (pacienteplanning.getValue() === pacientesource.getValue())
           if (coincidencia) { //Si coinciden los nombres
             var dia=planning.getCell(columna,18);
             var terapeuta=planning.getCell(columna,1);
             var hora=planning.getCell(1, b);
           if (diaprevio != dia.getValue()) {var nombredia = doc.appendParagraph("\n" + dia.getValue()); nombredia.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3); } // Si el día no es el mismo al previo, lo pone en HEADING.
             doc.getBody().appendParagraph(hora.getValue() + "    " + terapeuta.getValue()) //Escribe el resultado en el documento
           }   
         } 
         var diaprevio = dia.getValue()
         }              
    }
     var diaprevio = dia.getValue()+1;  //THIS IS WHERE I TRY TO CHANGE THE VALUE OF THE VARIABLE
     doc.getBody().appendPageBreak() //Salto de Página
     }
}
```

I would appreciate any help towards solving this problem. I think there's something about variable managing in this kind of script I still don't know.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You are making multiple variable declarations of the same variable.  I see that `diaprevio` is being declared multiple times.  You can declare a variable at the top of the function, and never use the `var` keyword twice for the same variable name.  You can declare a variable without assigning a value to it:  `var diaprevio;`  The value will be `undefined` in that example.  You can declare multiple variables with one `var` keyword.   `var activ, coincidencia, dia, diaprevio, planning, sheet;`  You could declare all those variables on the first line, and never use `var` again for any of them.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your function to extract all the `var` keywords out of the for loops.

Try this and see if it works.

```
/* Funciones para generar horarios a partir del calendario
Esta escanea las celdas de calendario de derecha a izquierda y arriba a abajo
Para encontrar el texto coincidente y lo entrega en un documento de texto.
*/

function TerapeutaHora() {

  var activ = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = activ.getActiveSheet(); //Selecciona la hoja activa, no una hoja fija
  var planning = sheet.getRange("A1:S36"); // Rango del calendario + la lista de días
  var ListaPacientes = sheet.getRange("A45:A72"); // Rango de los pacientes activos
  var dia=planning.getCell(1,1);
  var doc = DocumentApp.create("Horario"); // Crea un nuevo documento llamado Horario
  var docu = doc.getBody()

//Primero hacemos que pase por los pacientes activos
  var p, pacientesource, par, d, b, a, columna, pacientaplanning, coincidencia, dia, teraputa, hora, nmbredia;

  for (p=1; p < 29; p++) {
    pacientesource=ListaPacientes.getCell(p,1)

    par = docu.appendParagraph(pacientesource.getValue())
    par.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2) //Pone el nombre del paciente en HEADING

//Luego que pase por las filas y las columnas
    for (d = 0; d < 5; d++){ //cinco días
      for (b = 1; b < 18; b++){ //18 columnas de horario
        for (a = 3; a < 9; a++){ //Los 6 nombres
          columna = (d*7 +a) //Los 7 espacios entre un día y otro
          pacienteplanning=planning.getCell(columna, b) //Lee el paciente y lo compara con el que está eligiendo en este momento
          coincidencia = (pacienteplanning.getValue() === pacientesource.getValue())
          if (coincidencia) { //Si coinciden los nombres
            dia=planning.getCell(columna,18);
            terapeuta=planning.getCell(columna,1);
            hora=planning.getCell(1, b);
            if (diaprevio != dia.getValue()) {
              nombredia = doc.appendParagraph("\n" + dia.getValue()); 
              nombredia.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING3); 
            } // Si el día no es el mismo al previo, lo pone en HEADING.
            doc.getBody().appendParagraph(hora.getValue() + "    " + terapeuta.getValue()) //Escribe el resultado en el documento
          }   
        } 
        diaprevio = dia.getValue()
      }              
    }
    diaprevio = dia.getValue()+1;  //THIS IS WHERE I TRY TO CHANGE THE VALUE OF THE VARIABLE
    doc.getBody().appendPageBreak() //Salto de Página
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I overdid this defining of variables because of the examples I have read in the Internet to learn this script language. The last thing I had done with that was in Turbo C and Turbo Pascal in the nineties.
It works, unfortunately the error keeps happening. Somehow _diaprevio_ does not accept a new value. I have tried getting the debugger to work and follow the variable, but it does not.

Comment: I mean, `diaprevio` does not accept a new value other than `dia.getValue()`. May it have to do with the `for`loop? The bug shows up seldom, given that most patients end late in the week and begin early: I found it after two months using the script with a patient that begins in a Wednesday after a patient that finished on the same Wednesday.

Comment: I think the `for` loop has something to do: If I set `diaprevio=1` just below `diaprevio=dia.getValue()`, the function breaks down and repeats the day in every time entry (the result is day in bold, times for that day below, next day in bold again). BUT if I set `diaprevio=1` OUTSIDE of the `for (b = 1; b < 18; b++)` loop, nothing happens even if it's inside the `for (a...` loop, in which case the output should break down as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help. I found the variable that had to be reset was not `diaprevio` but `dia`. `diaprevio` was getting updated with the same `dia` in each iteration, so I pointed `dia` to an empty cell at the end of every patient.

You have helped me with the management of `var`. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you post your working code and mark the your answer as correct. You may help someone that has an issue similar to yours.